# Error: firebase.firestore().collection().doc(*) 'documentPath' must point to a document in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux, redux-saga

When I am trying to update my document in firebase I got an error like my topic.
After I upload my image to firebase storage and  I need to update the download link to my Users collection.(I used Redux-Saga for this process)

```
export function* uploadProfile(action) {
    console.log(action);
    const filePath = action.data.filePath;
    const fileName = action.data.fileName;
    const userID = action.data.userID;
    try {
        const uploadProfile = yield call(uploadFileFireBase, filePath, fileName)
        if (uploadProfile) {
            try {
                const updateProfile = yield call(updateUserFirebase, userID, uploadProfile)
               
                if (updateProfile) {

                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}


async function uploadFileFireBase(filePath, fileName) {
    const reference = storage().ref(fileName);
    await reference.putFile(filePath.toString());
    // console.log("Download URL:" + url)
    return await storage().ref(fileName).getDownloadURL();
}


/*
Update User Data
*/

function updateUserFirebase(uploadProfile, userID) {
    return firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(userID)
        .update({
            profileImage: uploadProfile,
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('User updated!');
            return data;
        });
}
```

I spent hours and hours trying to make this write and I couldn't.
So I really really need your help with this university project.
Thank you very much for your time.❤️❤️

Comment: What does it print when you print `uploadProfile` `userID` in `updateUserFirebase` at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @PRSHL userID = collection ID / uploadProfile = firebase storage image download link

Comment: yeah sure but does contain the expected data? I guess you may get not properly resolved promises or something

Comment: this error seems to be due to the missing collection reference, can you  check it and confirm ?